# Changing one of two objects that are the same in memory does not change the other object

Tags: python, immutability, mutable

Simply, I have two lists that are the same object, as

```
lines.append(l1)
lines[-1] is l1
>>True
```

This evaluates to True, so they should be the same point in memory. But when I make

```
l1=[]
lines[-1]==l1
>>False
```

I don't understand how two objects could point to the same point in memory, as `lines[-1] is l1` evaluates to true but then changing l1 does not change lines[-1].
The actual code I was using that caused this is

```
number=['0,9 -> 5,9', '8,0 -> 0,8', '9,4 -> 3,4', '2,2 -> 2,1', '7,0 -> 7,4', '6,4 -> 2,0', '0,9 -> 2,9', '3,4 -> 1,4', '0,0 -> 8,8', '5,5 -> 8,2']
lines=[]
for i in number:
    i=i.split("->")
    i[0]=i[0][:-1]
    i[1]=i[1][1:]
    
    s1 = i[0].split(",")
    s2 = i[1].split(",")
    l1 =[s1,s2]
    lines.append(l1) 
    print(l1==lines[-1],l1 is lines[-1]) #evalutes to True True
    l1=[]
    print(l1==lines[-1],l1 is lines[-1]) #evalutes to False False
    print(l1,lines[-1],"\n")
```

Like how could l1 be lines[-1], but changing l1 does not change lines[-1]?

I think the problem lies with assigning l1 to a new value. If I just did `l1.append(1)`, then the code works as expected. However, doing `l1 = [32,32]` or some other arbitrary assignment then the code does not work as expected.

Comment: Variables or names are _just_ references to objects, the assignment operator changes the object that a name references (or creates a new name), `lines[-1]` and `l1` are initially references to the same object and when you assign to `l1` they no longer reference the same object

Answer (score 0):

The reason the append method works is because it is an inplace operator. While an assignment just changes the memory address without changing the values at the previous memory address.